# is recursive explicit template instantiation possible?

Tags: c++, templates

Given a template like

```
template<int dim> class Point { ... };
```

this template can be instantiated explicitly like

```
template class Point<0>;
template class Point<1>;
template class Point<2>;
template class Point<3>;
```

instead of instantiating every template individually like above, I would like to instantiate them recursively with one call like

```
template class RecursiveInstantiate<Point, 3>;
```

where `RecursiveInstantiate<T, i>` would instantiate `T<i>`, `T<i-1>`, ..., `T<0>`. Is it somehow possible to create such a class `RecursiveInstantiate`? If it is not possible, do you know a way to do it with the preprocessor?

In fact I am interested in generalizing this for classes with multiple template parameters like`Node<int i1,int i2,int i3>` for all combination of i1,i2,i3 in {0,1,2,3}. But I hope to be able to work out this second part by myself.

Any advice, also an explanation why it is impossible what I want to achieve is appreciated.

---

**Update:** thank you for your comments so far. I see now more clearly where the problem really is. The line

```
template class Point<3>;
```

instantiates the template and exports its symbols to the object file. An instantiation of the form

```
template class RecursiveInstantiate<Point, 3>;
```

may instantiate the classes `class Point<3>`, `class Point<2>`, .... Apparently this only happens locally though. The templates are not exported to the object file. Maybe I will have to look for a solution using the preprocessor.

As I see now that I did not ask my question precisely enough in the beginning, I appreciate your answers and selected ones as correct.

**Note:** I am trying this on linux with g++/clang as compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make a little Instantiator class:

```
template <unsigned int N> struct Instantiator
{
  Point<N> p;
  Instantiator<N-1> i;
};

template <> struct Instantiator<0>
{
  Point<0> p;
};
```

Then simply add *one* explicit instantiation: `template struct Instantiator<81>;`

You can extend this idea lexicographically to any number of integral parameters.

---

As @Georg says, let's make it generic:

```
template <template <unsigned int> class T, unsigned int N> struct Instantiator
{
  T<N> t;
  Instantiator<T, N-1> i;
};

template <template <unsigned int> class T> struct Instantiator<T, 0>
{
  T<0> t;
};

template struct Instantiator<Point, 82>;
```

Comment: Make it `template<class T, unsigned N> struct I { T<N> p; I<T, N-1>; }; ...`. Also, using meta-algorithms & meta-functions would avoid hard-coding parameter counts (see what Boost.MPL does).

Comment: This solution looks very nice, I really like your generic solution. I still have struggles getting this to work. The approach compiles nicely, yes, but somehow the symbols for `Point<0>` are not exported into the object file, which is what the code `template class Point<0>;` would be doing. I will have to investigate this further tomorrow.  

I am using g++/clang on Linux, but I'm not sure if this is specific to my architecture.

Comment: I'm not sure this actually works. No variation of this that I've tried actually produces anything in an object file.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like this:

```
template<int dim> struct Point {
    static const int val = dim;
    Point<dim - 1> p;
};

template<> struct Point<0> { ... };
```

That creates a template specialisation for the template parameter when it is `0` so the recursion stops there, and when you instantiate one like this:

```
Point<4>
```

It instantiates from `Point<4>` down to `Point<0>`. Then you can do

```
Point<4>::val
```

to access the value of that particular one.

Comment: That requires modifying and having control over the definition of `Point`, though.

Comment: @Kerrek the concept can easily be extended to be used without modifying `Point`.

Comment: This approach did not work for me. If I instantiate `template class Point<4>;` then only the symbols for `Point<4>` get exported into the object file, not the other symbols, although indeed the recursion is correctly executed by the compiler.